# Compact Connected Hausdorff Space has no compact component in the complement of a point

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff Compact Connected Space. Prove that $X\setminus\{x\}$ can't be expressed by the disjoint union of two connected sets with one them being compact.(lets assume the empty set is connected)

So, I tried a demonstration by contradiction:

If $X\setminus\{x\}$ is connected, then if $X\setminus\{x\}$ is compact, it's a closed subspace of $X$ (because $X$ is Hausdorff) and therefore it's a clopen on $X$. So, $X\setminus\{x\}$ can't be disconnected. Assume that there are disjoint connected sets $U$ and $V$ of $X\setminus\{x\}$ such that  $$X\setminus\{x\} = U \cup V$$
And $U$ is a compact set. $U$ can't be open on $X\setminus \{x\}$ (or otherwise it'd be a clopen set of $X$). But as $U \cup V =X= \cup_{i\in I} A_i$ with $A_i$ open connected subsets of $X\setminus \{x\}$. Because $U$ is connected, $U \subset A_{i_1}$ and the same goes to $V \subset A_{i_2}$. $X \subset U \cup V \subset A_{i_1} \cup A_{i_2}$. Because $X$ is not connected, $i_1 \neq i_2$. Also, because $A_{i_2} \cap U = \emptyset$ and then $A_{i_2} = V$ and therefore $U = A_{i_1}$ and $U$ is open, a contradiction.

> As it is stated, the proposition is false (check Brian's answer). I've corrected it in another question: [Complement of a point of a Compact Connected Hausdorff Space has no compact maximal connected subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107062/complement-of-a-point-of-a-compact-connected-hausdorff-space-has-no-compact-maxi)

Comment: I suspect that you are missing the condition that the subsets in question are connected components of $X -\{x\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Revised and corrected to match the edited question.**

The statement is false. Let $X=[0,2]$ with the usual topology, and let $x=0$. Then

$$X\setminus\{x\}=(0,2]=(0,1)\cup[1,2]\;,$$

where $(0,1)$ and $[1,2]$ are disjoint and connected, and $[1,2]$ is compact.

Comment: Why would I use Hasdorfness to show that $K$ is open in $X$? To show that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes. (Of course you’re really just using the $T_1$ property here.)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm sorry I made a terrible mistake in the question. I'll edit it. My components are not necessarily open.

Comment: @Jonas: The statement in its present form is false: see my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I lost a lot of time trying to prove a false statement with an obvious counter-example!

Comment: @JonasGomes: Doesn't *disjoint union of $A$ and $B$* mean that the space has the topology with respect to these subspaces, i.e. a set is open if its intersection with each of the two sets is open in that set?

Comment: @Stefan: Depends on who’s using it and on the context. Here I would not understand it that way. If it *is* intended that way, the stated result is true and fairly trivial: both sets must be open in $X$ as well as in $X\setminus\{x\}$, so $K$ is clopen in $X$, which is impossible.

Comment: Oh, right, I did not see that the result is trivial in that case. So I think you are right and it indeed means that $X$ is just the disjoint union of these **sets**.

Comment: The components are supposed to me maximal connexed sets, I'll post another question with this modification, thanks BrianMScott and @StefanHamcke

Comment: I've posted the new question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107062/complement-of-a-point-of-a-compact-connected-hausdorff-space-has-no-compact-maxi