# Complement of a point of a Compact Connected Hausdorff Space has no compact maximal connected subspace

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

This question is a slight modified version of [Compact Connected Hausdorff Space has no compact component in the complement of a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105968/compact-connected-hausdorff-space-has-no-compact-component-in-the-complement-of)

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff Compact Connected Space. Prove that $X∖\{x\}$ has no compact component (here a component is a maximal connected subspace).

(My attempt is in the question linked above)

Comment: It's true if $X$ is locally connected, at least, with an easy proof (the component would be non-trivial clopen subset of $X$). This fact should hold for *all* $x$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96743/4280) the following lemma is proved:

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $C \subset X$ have a compact
>   neighbourhood $K$. Then $C$ is a component of $X$ if and only if
>   $C$ is a component of $K$

Also:

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $Y$ an open subspace and $Z$ a closed
>   subspace.
>   Let $C$ be a connected subset of $Y \cap Z$ such that $C$ is a component
>   of $Y$ and a component of $Z$. Then $C$ is a component of $Y\cup Z$.

which can be simplified to (as per the remark by Hamcke on that answer): if $X$ is a compact normal space and $Y$ is an open subset of $X$, then a compact connected component of $Y$ is also a connected component for $X$.

This applies directly to your question: your $X$ is compact and normal (follows from compact plus Hausdorff) and $Y = X \setminus \{x\}$ is open, and if $C$ were a compact component of $Y$ it would be one for $X$ but this cannot be, as the only connected component for $X$ is $X$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need some time to look it trough and understand all the details.

Comment: Actually, $C$ must be closed, not compact, in order to apply the normality.

Comment: @StefanHamcke compactness was in the original question, so that case is enough... And compact implies closed here anyway.